# TransitionDrawable not working inside custom view's onDraw

Tags: android, android-custom-view, android-drawable

I am trying to start [TransitionDrawable](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/drawable/TransitionDrawable.html) startTransition() method inside onTouchEvent() of a custom view. It only shows the first image in the xml file. It however works on `ImageView`'s `setDrawable()` method. Combining these two is it possible or are there other alternative to show similar transition in a custom view.

transition.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<transition xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/ic_icon_lock"/> // only this image is shown
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/ic_icon_unlock"/>
</transition>
```

Initializer:

```
mLockTransitionalDrawable = (TransitionDrawable)
            ResourcesCompat.getDrawable(mResources, R.drawable.transition, mContext.getTheme());
```

onDraw() custom view:

```
mLockTransitionalDrawable.setBounds(mLockRect);
    mLockTransitionalDrawable.draw(canvas);
```

Fired when Action down happens inside the rectangle(mLockRect) containing the drawable:

```
 mLockTransitionalDrawable.startTransition(1000); // does not change drawable layer invalidate() requestLayout() is not working either
```

I am looking for a simple solution because of time constraints.

Comment: you need to set up a Callback

Comment: Drawable.Callback why did not I think about that I will give it a try and attempt to answer my own question thanks @pskink

Comment: also i think `TransitionDrawable` works with two `Drawable`s only

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to *pskink*'s comment I got it working. Heres some relevant code.

Create `Drawable.Callback` object or implement it:

```
mLockTransitionCallback = new Drawable.Callback() {
        @Override
        public void invalidateDrawable(Drawable who) {
            Log.e("invalidate called", "yes");
            invalidate(mLockRect);// don't call invalidate() it will invalidate the whole canvas I am only invalidating the region that I want to redraw

        }

        @Override
        public void scheduleDrawable(Drawable who, Runnable what, long when) {
            new Handler().postAtTime(what, who, when);// this will start the animation

        }

        @Override
        public void unscheduleDrawable(Drawable who, Runnable what) {
            Log.e("unschedule called","yes");
        }
    };
```

Set the callback:

```
mLockTransitionalDrawable.setCallback(mLockTransitionCallback);
```

Comment: well, you can use your View as a Drawable.Callback ... (View implements Drawable.Callback) in your implementation `new Handler().postAtTime` could be called several times making new Handler each time

Comment: @pskink you are right I will create a separate handler and not initialize it on schedule drawable

Comment: as i said: you dont need to implement the whole Callback interface, its already done in View class, from what you are saying you are creating a custom View, so use it as a Callback